# I tried to run a google map v2 in an android device.But receiving same errors all the time. I couldnt solve it. Can anyone help me?

Tags: android

```
01-25 04:26:17.689: I/Process(1070): Sending signal. PID: 1070 SIG: 9

01-25 04:26:39.769: E/Trace(1089): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

01-25 04:26:40.189: D/AndroidRuntime(1089): Shutting down VM

01-25 04:26:40.189: W/dalvikvm(1089): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Simple.lastmap/com.Simple.lastmap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at com.Simple.lastmap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     ... 11 more

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4132500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at 
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.eb(Unknown Source)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4716)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)

01-25 04:26:40.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     ... 20 more
```

Comment: Can you paste your onCreateView inflate ?

Comment: Post your code First.

Comment: Post your code...Refer this one http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/google-maps-in-android-application-with-new-google-maps-android-api-v2-using-supportmapfragment/

Answer (score 0):

Please take the Reference from this it will help you :[link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/)